# ¿ como puedo impedir que la se inserte una fecha de fin que es menor a la de inico?

Tags: html, css, laravel-7

tengo una vista editar evento, necesito saber si  esposibel impedir que al editar los campos de hora inicio y hora final se inserte una hora final que sea menor a la de inicio y de igual manera impedir que se inserte una hora de inicio mayor a la de final, pero esto sin tener que recargar la pagina, es decir que si yo en la pagina de editar evento cambie la hora de inicio se valide de una vez la hora de final para que pueda poner la hora final mayor a la de inicio. ejemplo:

*cuando se creo el evento se creo con estas horas

> hora inicio:13:00
> hora fin:14:00

es decir que si yo quiero ingresar una hora de fin menor a la de inicio que me lo impida sin tener que guardar los cambios

*cuando se edite

> hora inicio:12:00
> hora fin:13:00

pero de igual manera si yo cambio la hora de inicio que la validacion del impedimento se actualice para que si yo cambie hora inicio a 12pm que me impida poner una hora fin menor a la nueva hora de inicio.

aqui mi vista:

```
@extends('Admin.layout')

@section('admincontent')
<div class="text-center">
    <br>
    <h2>EDITAR EVENTOS</h2>
    <hr style="width:1080px; height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 70rem;">       
    <div class="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header text-left">
        <a href=" {{route ('Admin.DetalleEvento', $event)}}" style="padding-left: 10px;" title="Back">
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm "><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Back</button></a>
          <h2 class="text-center" >Editando el evento #{{$event->id}}</h2>
        </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <br>
            <form action="{{ route('eventos.actualizarEvento', $event)}}" method="POST">
              @method('PUT')
              @csrf

              @error('HoraInicioEvento')
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                La hora de inicio es obligatoria
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
              </div>
            @enderror

            @error('HoraFinalEvento')
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
              La hora final es obligatoria
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
              </div>
            @enderror

            @error('FechaEvento')
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
              La fecha es obligatoria
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
              </div>
            @enderror

            @error('DescripcionEvento')
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                La descripcion es obligatoria
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
              </div>
            @enderror

            @if(session('mensaje'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
              {{session ('mensaje')}}
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
            </div>
            @endif
            
            @error('idEvento')
                      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                      </span>
                    @enderror

            @error('idTramo')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                  @enderror

                  @error('idEncargado')
                      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                      </span>
                    @enderror


            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="idTramo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Tramo') }}</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <select name="idTramo" id="idTramo" class="forms control input-sm col-md-12 col-form-label text-md-right">
                  @foreach ($Tramo_array as $data)                                       
                  <option value="{{ $data->id }}"  >{{ $data->NombreTramo }}</option>                                                      
                  @endforeach
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="idEvento" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Tipo de Evento') }}</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <select name="idEvento" id="idEvento" class="forms control input-sm col-md-12 col-form-label text-md-right">
                      @foreach ($NombreEvento_array as $data)                                       
                        <option value="{{ $data->id }}"  >{{ $data->NombreEvento }}</option>                                                      
                      @endforeach
                  </select>
                </div> 
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="idEncargado" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Encargado') }}</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <select name="idEncargado" id="idEncargado" class="forms control input-sm col-md-12 col-form-label text-md-right">
                    @foreach ($User_array as $data) 
                        @if($data->IdTipoUsurio == 1)                                      
                          <option value="{{ $data->id }}"  >{{ $data->name }}</option>  
                        @endif                                                    
                    @endforeach
                 </select>
                </div> 
              </div>
                
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="HoraInicioEvento" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ 'Hora inicio del evento' }}</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="time" 
                        name="HoraInicioEvento" 
                        placeholder="Hora inicio del evento" 
                        class="form-control mb-2" value="{{ $event->HoraInicioEvento }}">
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="HoraFinalEvento" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ 'Hora final del evento' }}</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="time" 
                      name="HoraFinalEvento" 
                      placeholder="Hora final del evento" 
                      class="form-control mb-2" value="{{ $event->HoraFinalEvento }}" min="{{ $event->HoraInicioEvento }}">
                  </div> 
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="FechaEvento" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ 'Fecha del evento' }}</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="date" 
                      name="FechaEvento" 
                      placeholder="Fecha del evento" 
                      class="form-control mb-2" value="{{ $event->FechaEvento }}" min="{{date('Y-m-d')}}">
                  </div> 
              </div>


              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="DescripcionEvento" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ 'Descripción del evento' }}</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" 
                       name="DescripcionEvento" 
                       placeholder="Descripcion" 
                       class="form-control mb-2" value="{{ $event->DescripcionEvento }}">
                  </div> 
              </div>
                  <img src="images/{{$event->ImagenEvento}}" >
                <input id="images" name="ImagenEvento"  type="file" value="{{$event->ImagenEvento}}"><br>
              </div>

              <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block" type="submit">Editar</button>
            </form>
          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Que has intentado? Lee [ask]

Comment: de momento lo que hecho es poner en el input min="{{ $event->HoraInicioEvento }}" pero eso solo valida al momento de darle al boton de guardarr cambios, claro al momento de cambiar la hora de fin por otra menor a la de inicio que esta en la tabla evento si te lo dice, pero si quiero cambiar la hora de inicio y de fin al mismo tiempo no me deja

Comment: Si no quieres que la página se recargue entonces necesitas AJAX para que al momento de mandar una fecha se procese esa petición, añade lo que lleves al momento sobre eso